# Why using Tomcat and not "java -jar"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm creating a job in jenkins to deploy a springboot application to Tomcat.
I'm trying to understand why should I deploy an application to Tomcat? Why not just run the application on the server by "java -jar" command?

In my previous workplace we deployed the springboot application by creating a war file and "java -jar" command. We used "kill" to shut down the application and "java -jar" again to deploy a new version...

I understand that Tomcat has a big advantage here and I would like to understand what is it?

Google says me how to work with tomcat but I couldn't find a real explanation **why** need it except [this](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war#:%7E:text=It%20provides%20a%20management%20dashboard%20from%20which%20you%20can%20deploy%20a%20new%20web%20application%2C%20or%20undeploy%20an%20existing%20one%20without%20having%20to%20restart%20the%20container.%20This%20is%20especially%20useful%20in%20production%20environments.) that says:

> It provides a management dashboard from which you can deploy a new web application, or undeploy an existing one without having to restart the container. This is especially useful in production environments.

But what do I have to manage here?

Comment: This was the outdated way of doing things, and some companies are still stuck in 2010.

Comment: Springboot is probably [using tomcat](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications) even if running from a jar

Comment: Tomcat provides infrastructure that the built-in web container doesn't (things like AJP connectors and the previously mentioned admin interface). If you don't need those and only ever want a single web application per JVM, then it's not really necessary. It's the older, but also move involved version of deploying it. Note that "normal" WAR files *need* some kind of container (like Tomcat), but Spring Boot adds some additional code to allow self-hosting using `java -jar`.

Comment: modern web frameworks like ratpack or vert.x do NOT use tomcat neither standalone nor embedded, like springboot does (by default). Hence they are to be started with "java -jar"